# How can I select and copy some files from several directories and paste to another folder?

Tags: windows, copy-paste

In windows by now, only can select multiple files in same directory and paste to another. But I want select and copy some files from several directories and paste to another folder. Is there any solution for that ? I mean something like , when going to paste to folder ask which one you want to paste and show last 05 copied items.

Comment: Why can't you just copy and paste like you do with any other windows file?

Comment: yes can paste. but just think, if I wanted to copy some files in 5 separate directories to a new folder, I have to copy and paste 5 times.